# Add columns data in python

Tags: python

A text file containing data which has three columns and 43 rows .i want to add rest two columns on the basis of first columns, actually I want to calculate the weight of first numbers

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4RMZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It sounds like you want the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html), as another commenter suggested, however requests for packages or libraries are explicitly off topic for this site. For more assistance, please provide a [mcve] including sample input and output as text in your question, and code for what you've already tried

Comment: i read 1 2 3  from text file i want to check if first number is 1 then add 2+3  and print like 1=5

Comment: This question is far too broad/vague. What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly, I think you need something like this

```py
# file.txt
1 2 3
2 4 5


# script.py
with open('a.txt', 'r') as f: 
   lines = f.readlines() 

output = [] 
for line in lines: 
   a, b, c = map(int, line.split()) 
   output.append([line.strip(), a*(b+c), '\n']) 

with open('output.txt', 'a+') as f: 
   for line in output: 
      f.write(" ".join(map(str, line))) 


# output.txt
1 2 3 5 
2 4 5 18
```

Comment: Thanks you Sir. yes i need this

Comment: @ArslanHanif Please mark this answer as your solution if it's solved. And do some searches before asking questions.